# How do I use Tellraw Selectors on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m trying to get a custom “player joined the game” message on my bedrock edition world but it won’t work. When I type

```
/tellraw @a {“rawtext”:[{“text”:”hi “},{“selector”:”@p”}]}
```

it doesn’t error but in chat it only says `hi`. I’ve tried searching a bunch of sites but I can’t find anything. Does anybody have any ideas? I really don’t want to use a say command because of the brackets.